# how to determine the expected value of the first element of an ordered statistic

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

> let $X$ be a random variable with density
>   $$f_x(x) = e^{\alpha-x} \: x>a$$
>   (a) what is the maximum likelihood estimator for alpha
>   (b) make the estimator in (a) unbiased, and evaluate its variance

so without much explaination, it should be obvious that the likelihood function is maximized when $\alpha = X_{(1)}$, i.e. the first ordered element in the random sample of random variables. 
e.g. $$ln(L_X(X)) = ln\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n{e^{\alpha-x_i}}\right) = n\alpha - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i}$$ (which is naturally maximized at the maximum possible value for $\alpha$, which is $X_{(1)}$)

my question is: how can I evaluate the bias of $X_{(1)}$? This is what I have so far:

first, I need to calculate the expected value of $X_{(1)}$, since the definition of bias is: $$B[\Gamma] = E[\Gamma]-\gamma$$

to calculate $E[X_{(1)}]$, I need the pdf of $X_{(1)}$, which I derive using the following reasoning:
$$P(X<t) = \int_{\alpha}^t{e^{\alpha-x}dx} = 1-e^{\alpha-t}$$

$$P(X_{(1)}<t) = P(X_{(2)}>t)P(X_{(3)}>t)...P(X_{(n)}>t) = (e^{\alpha-x})^{n-1}$$
so the pdf of $X_{(1)}$ is: 
$$\frac{\partial P(X_{(1)}<t)}{\partial x} = (n-1)(e^{\alpha-x})^{n-2}$$

and so, the expected value of $X_{(1)}$ is: 
$$E[X_{(1)}] = 
\int_\alpha^\infty{x(n-1)(e^{\alpha-x})^{n-2}dx} = 
\frac{(n-1)(\alpha(n-2)+1)}{(n-2)^2}$$

which isn't exactly the most meaningful expression. The answer in the back of the book suggests that $X_{(1)}-\dfrac{1}{n}$ is an unbiased estimator, suggesting the $E[X_{(1)}] = \alpha+\dfrac{1}{n}$, however, I have no clue how they came up with this...

any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Shoot, I think I just figured it out. I made a mistake in the derivative of the PDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it turns out I made a pretty bozo mistake: When deriving the CDF, I should have noticed that:

$$P(X_{(1)}>x) = P(X_{1}>x)P(X_{2}>x)P(X_{3}>x)\cdots P(X_{n}>x) = (e^{\alpha-x})^{n}$$
so the pdf of $X_{(1)}$ is: 
$$-\frac{\partial P(X_{(1)}>x)}{\partial x} = n(e^{\alpha-x})^{n}$$

and so, the expected value of $X_{(1)}$ is: 
$$E[X_{(1)}] = \int_\alpha^\infty{x n(e^{\alpha-x})^{n}dx} = \frac{1}{n}+\alpha$$